# Backbone.js and setInterval: How to check if something is already in the DOM

Tags: jquery, dom, backbone.js

I'm adding a call to `setInterval` on my `fetch` call (in my collection), and it created an unintended side effect.  Here's the view that is calling the collection:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/tableModel',
    'collections/tablesCollection',
    'views/tableView'
],
function($, _, Backbone, tableModel, tablesCollection, tableView) {
    var tablesView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'div',
        initialize: function(options) {
            this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
            this.template = this.options.template;
            this.url = this.options.url;
        },
        render: function() {
            this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
            return this;
        },
        addOne: function(model) {
            var TableView = new tableView({ model: model, template: this.template, url: this.url });
            $(this.$el).append(TableView.render().el);
            return this;
        }
    });

    return tablesView;
});
```

As you can see, this view iterates through the collection, appending each lead to the DOM, which is what I want.  But with the call to `setInterval` it does this every time the collection is fetched.  This is what I want, but I want to add a line before the `append` to check to see if the item is in the DOM already.  I figured I could use `model.get('id')` possibly and compare it against the DOM.  Is this best approach?  If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic/naive pattern for this type of thing is to have a render method following this pattern:

```
render: function() {
    this.$el.empty()
    this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
    return this;
}
```

Otherwise your DOM and collection will get out of sync, as you have noticed. If you are doing something really intense (which is also probably ill-advised) like refetching your collection every 100ms or rendering 5000 models, you may need a much more sophisticated approach, but these are code smells that your approach is wrong. If you want something realtime, check out socket.io and pub/sub. If you are going to do server polling with setInterval, just KISS and empty the view and rerender everything.

Since you asked, if you ever do need to avoid a re-render with manual (and fragile) checking, put a `data-id="<%= model.id %>"` attribute on the outermost tag of the model view and then check `this.$('[data-id=' + model.id + ']').length` to determine if it's in the DOM already or not.

Comment: Thanks, Peter.  I knew there had to be a way to do that.

Comment: That second part does sound a little sketchy now that I hear it.  I like your first method best.  Thanks again.